# Does Einstein work with Salesforce 2 Salesforce?

Tags: einstein-analytics, salesforce2salesforce

We have three different Salesforce instances in our organization. If we implement Salesforce 2 Salesforce and bring in all the data in one chosen instance, will Einstein work to show the reports from the destination instance ?

Comment: Einstein syncs data from Salesforce objects into its own database.  Salesforce 2 Salesforce copies only Salesforce objects, not external databases like Einstein, Pardot, etc.  The Einstein in your destination instance should pick up all the Salesforce records brought in via S2S, but you should check with Einstein support.

Answer (score 1):

Einstein syncs data from Salesforce objects into its own database. Salesforce 2 Salesforce copies only Salesforce objects, not external databases like Einstein, Pardot, etc. The Einstein in your destination instance should pick up all the Salesforce records brought in via S2S, but you should check with Einstein support.